# Where is Abinitio configuration for ETL is stored?

Tags: parsing, configuration, ab-initio

There are about 200+ Abinitio ETL configurations that I have. I would like to know where the ETL configurations are stored. Abinition is installed in linux box, I could access the DML configuration which just lists the fields and the corresponding data type, other than that not sure where the other configurations are stored.

Need the following information (not just limited to the listing below)

1. Source datastore, table
2. Destination datastore, table
3. Graph and the steps that forms the pipeline
4. Custom transformation or logic
5. List of source and the corresponding mapping to the destination store fields
6. Branching and convergence logic

One way to do is use the Abinitio GDE, since there are 200+ graphs to be viewed manually that is not possible manually. If the configurations are available, then could attempt writing a parser to extract the needed information.

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 0):

all configs stored in EME TR (Ab Initio version control system), if you are using it.

all configs/jobs/plans are stored in PLAIN text format.

Graph/Execution plans has file extension .MP

> One way to do is use the Abinitio GDE, since there are 200+ graphs to be viewed manually that is not possible manually. If the configurations are available, then could attempt writing a parser to extract the needed information.

extract/checkout all files from EME TR to your local PC.
use Search inside files by using GREP/MC/FAR/any other tool you like